# Why the render result is different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

With the subsurface modifier i made the model. In the 3D view it look good

[image]

In the preview render also looks good <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

But when i click <kbd>F12</kbd> start render i get this unsubsurface result

[image]

May i know the reason why the result is different. I copy the only the model  in a new file and render same result. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Click on the camera icon of your Subdivision Surface modifier